# WinRT sideloaded app crash reports

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, crash-reports, crash-dumps

I have a sideloaded application in company and want to collect crash-reports and logs for this app.

How I can do this? I know App sends data to Windows Store Developer Center, but I haven't one because of sideloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE 1**

Check out my library [WinrtErrLog](https://github.com/Xyroid/WinrtErrLog). [Detailed blog about how to use, **not by me**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/690019/WinRT-Apps-Exception-Logging)

---

There are couple of paid libraries available that will deliver crash logs.

[MarkedUp](https://markedup.com/)

[BugSense](https://www.bugsense.com/)

[Raygun](http://raygun.io/)

You can also create own web service which stores the exception log in database.